# NPM Resolution Error: Conflicting Peer Dependency in multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2

Tags: node.js, node-modules, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I am encountering an NPM resolution error while trying to update the 'multer-gridfs-storage' package to version 5.0.2. The error seems to be related to conflicting peer dependencies with the 'multer' package.

**Error Message:**

```
While resolving: multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
Found: multer@1.4.5-lts.1
node_modules/multer
  multer@"^1.4.5-lts.1" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer multer@"^1.4.2" from multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage
  multer-gridfs-storage@"^5.0.2" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: multer@1.4.4
node_modules/multer
  peer multer@"^1.4.2" from multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
  node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage
    multer-gridfs-storage@"^5.0.2" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

**Issue Description:**
I am attempting to update the `multer-gridfs-storage` package to version 5.0.2 in my Node.js project. However, I am facing a resolution error with conflicting peer dependencies related to the `multer` package. The current version of `multer` in my project is `1.4.5-lts.1`, and `multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2` requires `multer@"^1.4.2"` as a peer dependency.

I have tried using the `npm audit fix --force` command to resolve the issue, but the error persists. I understand that using `--force` may introduce breaking changes, so I would prefer to find a proper resolution to this conflict.

I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this NPM peer dependency conflict for the `multer-gridfs-storage` package. How can I update the package without compromising my project's stability and security?